# How do I change decimal place in stored column data?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I shift the decimal place to the right two spots, and only keep one decimal point please?

Current data:

```
4 Year Grad Rate
0.799204771371769
```

I need the following stored in the column instead:

```
4 Year Grad Rate
79.9
```

I think I can use CAST to make it display the way I want, but I want to change the way the data is stored in the column to only have 2 digits, a decimal point, and then one digit.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply with 100 to move the decimal places and then cast to cut the unnecessary rest

```
select cast(0.799204771371769 * 100 as decimal(10,1))
```

#### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/40006)

To update your data you can do

```
update your_table
set your_column = cast(your_column * 100 as decimal(10,1))
```

Comment: Thanks @Juergen d.  The data looks correct, (which helps!) but I need to replace the long number with 79.9 in the column so I an query that moving forward, all I see is the 79.9.  CAST does not change the way the data is stored.

Comment: Thanks Juergen!  I used both your answer and @Blams to get me what I needed.  I

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure you could just change the column to `Decimal(9,1)`
Safe bet is create a new column `Decimal(9,1)`

I think you could just `set newCol = oldCol * 100.0;`

or

```
newCol = oldCol * 100D;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use Numeric Data Type in SQL SERVER

```
Numeric(p,s)
```

> p=The maximum total number of decimal digits that will be stored, 
>   both to the left and to the right of the decimal point.
>
> s=The number of decimal digits that will be stored  to the right of
>   the decimal point.

```
declare @val NUMERIC(18,2)=0.799204771371769
    select @val
```

EDIT:

```
declare @val NUMERIC(18,1)=0.799204771371769*100
select @val
```

Comment: Thanks @Ganesh_Devlekar, but when I run this, it gives me '.80'.  I need '79.9'stored in the column moving forward.  Am I missing something?  Thanks again.

Comment: @JM1 Updated now gives 79.9

Comment: You are correct, it now shows 79.9. Thank you.  How do I ensure that 79.9 is what is stored in that column moving forward, so when I query it, it only shows 79.9?

Comment: set datatype to `NUMERIC(18,1)` which stores 18 digits before decimal and 1 digit after decimal

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ROUND(0.799204771371769 * 100, 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ndech.  When I run it, it gives me '
79.900000000000000'.

Comment: What is the type of the target column ? As the other answers suggested, it should be numeric(xx,1) if you want to store only one decimal.

Comment: Do I have to create a new target column to store if differently?  If so, decimal should be fine.  Thanks @Ndech